# AdMob After Ad receive - IOException connecting to ad url

Tags: android, admob, ads

i have an android app that need to show ads by AdMob.
here's my Log:

```
07-18 01:55:53.116: INFO/Ads(8682): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"u_sd":1.5,"slotname":"**************","u_w":320,"msid":"com.paladin.hilula","cap":"m","adtest":"on","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0","isu":"*********************************","format":"320x50_mb","net":"ed","app_name":"1.android.com.paladin.hilula","hl":"hd","u_h":569,"testing":1,"u_audio":1,"u_so":"p"});</script></head><body></body></html>
07-18 01:55:54.187: INFO/Ads(8682): Received ad url: <"url": "http://r.admob.com:80/ad_source.php?preqs=0&u_sd=1.5&slotname=**************&u_w=320&msid=com.paladin.hilula&cap=m&adtest=on&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0&isu=*************************&format=320x50_mb&net=ed&app_name=1.android.com.paladin.hilula&hl=hd&u_h=569&testing=1&u_audio=1&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=-180&ex=1&client_sdk=1", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682): IOException connecting to ad url.
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:357)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:204)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:983)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:75)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at b.a(Unknown Source)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at b.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
07-18 01:56:15.288: WARN/Ads(8682):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
07-18 01:56:15.296: INFO/Ads(8682): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
```

i get the URL but cant show it.

in manifest:

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

in .java:

```
    // Create the adView
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlayout);
    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);
    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    AdRequest r = new AdRequest();
    r.setTesting(true);
    r.addTestDevice("*****************************");

    adView.loadAd(r);
```

Answer (score 10):

The /etc/hosts file on your phone has aliased r.admob.com to 127.0.0.1. I had this occur when I used a flashed ROM on my phone -- the ROM defined a whole bunch of entries like that so I'd never get ads. Which was great until I was testing my own ad-enabled app :-)

Edit your /etc/hosts and take out that entry.

Comment: Thank you SO much; there is no way in a billion years I would have figured this out on my own!

Answer (score 0):

AdMob's server (like any high volume server) can take too long to respond sometimes.  It is better that you design with failure like this as expected behavior.

If you think there is more to it than that. Post what you are seeing that makes you think something else may be going on.

Comment: the problem is that i dont see anything that can give me any clue about what's going on there...  
in my AdMob Acc. i can see the green indication about getting ad requests.

when i take the url i received, i get a testing ad in my browser... but nothing in the device, not even a blank AdView.

i've tested it in a few devices and few networks...